# How to set backlog size unlimited?

Tags: java, sockets

How to set the ServerSocket connection limit unlimited ?

I checked 
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12981957/java-serversocket-connection-limit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The backlog is only the number of Socket you haven't accepted which can be queued.  Normally 50 is more than enough.  You can make the limit much higher but if you need more than a few hundred you have a serious design issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The backlog is a queue in the kernel, and the kernel doesn't have infinite memory available to it. Nor would you want it to. The question doesn't really make sense.