# Android Client - Java Server: how many clients can a server support at the same time?

Tags: java, android, mysql, jdbc, client-server

I did not find any adequate answers to my question on Internet. So, I am asking here.
Here is my situation:
I am building an Android application where Android clients need to communicate with each other by passing through a Java-sql server (on the same port). I created the client and server sides but i am wondering what components i should take in count in order to have a server able to handle several thousand of clients ? Let's say for instance 2000 clients.
Is a high bandwidth for the server enough to achieve my goal ? (number of connections = bandwidth of server / average bandwidth of client).
Or a combination between the bandwidth of clients and server, CPU and RAM is necessary ?

I would appreciate any help.

Best regards,

Comment: There is no simple answer to a question like this. It depends on the implementation of the server software, on the hardware configuration like number of CPUs, core-count, RAM, and a lot of other things. Furthermore, it depends on what exactly your client-/server-software does per connection, if the connection are persistent connections like with SSH or more temporary like with HTTP. You're question as it is cannot be answered properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ServerSocket Docs Says:](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#ServerSocket%28int%29)`The maximum queue length for incoming connection indications (a request to connect) is set to 50. If a connection indication arrives when the queue is full, the connection is refused.`

Max. number of clients will vary by some amount every time depending  on your processing time, more CPU + RAM is always helpful at the server-side but code should be optimal also at the server-side.

High bandwidth server will only help you recive/send data to/from your clients but the processing time is also important(CPU + RAM + CODE).

Also take a look at this [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12982363/3326331) which talks about the same issue.

**Edit:**

As Mjoellnir said : *"Furthermore, it depends on what exactly your client-/server-software does per connection, if the connection are persistent connections like with SSH or more temporary like with HTTP"*, you should also take this particulat case into account.

Comment: This is about reacting on incoming connects, only. It is just one aspect of the question.